# Dynamic query creation based on user checkbox selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to build an app where user can select multiple checkboxes .
i need to build a dynamic query to fetch data from database but getting error .
here is my controller code for dynamic query .

```
if params[:food_type] != nil
      params[:food_type].each do |food_type|
         query_string << ' OR ' unless query_string.empty?
        query_string << 'food_type = ?'
        query_values  << food_type 

     end
   end
     wrev["wrev"]  = SearchResult.where(query_string, query_values)
         @pgresults << wrev
         wrev = {}

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @pgresults }
```

i am getting error as "prepared statement invalid (wrong number of bind variables).
i have defined

```
query_string = String.new
   query_values = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass "query_string" as part of "query_values" as one array, see [method where documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where):

```
if params[:food_type] != nil
      params[:food_type].each do |food_type|
         query_string << ' OR ' unless query_string.empty?
        query_string << 'food_type = ?'
        query_values  << food_type 

     end
   end
     query_values.unshift(query_string) #add the string at the beginning of the array
     wrev["wrev"]  = SearchResult.where(query_values) #passing the arrary with the query string and the values as just one array.
         @pgresults << wrev
         wrev = {}

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @pgresults }
```